# Any option to get larger amount (i.e. 2000) of Rinkeby Ether?

Tags: ether, ropsten, rinkeby, faucets

We are planning to open our product to the public for live testing. We want to support both Ropsten and Rinkeby networks, just in case.

When registering, each user should get around 10 ether on their account so that they can freely play around with the product. The product is an abstraction layer over a blockchain implementation, so we do not want users to have to deal with faucets in order to get it. Because of that, we would like to fill our main account with enough ether so that we can redistribute them to the users when necessary.

For Ropsten, that is easy because we can automate withdrawal from the faucet.

For Rinkeby that approach is not possible, because of the social network account limitation.

Do you know of any other way to get a one-time injection of larger amount of Rinkeby ether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know of any other way to get a one-time injection of larger amount of Rinkeby ether?

You'd probably have to convince the network admins that you're not up to mischief...

The [current faucet](https://faucet.rinkeby.io/) limits things for the following reason:

> To prevent malicious actors from exhausting all available funds or
>   accumulating enough Ether to mount long running spam attacks, requests
>   are tied to common 3rd party social network accounts.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know where can i find contacts of network admins?

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: Waiting for a little bit more information before marking it as accepted, for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Good question - I think your best bet might be to try in the Geth Gitter chatroom, and ask there. (Noting that Rinkeby only runs on the Geth client.) -> https://gitter.im/ethereum/go-ethereum?source=orgpage (I couldn't find an obvious way to contact anyone running the network, I'm afraid.)